# light not passing through a transparent object in eevee render engine

Tags: eevee-render-engine, light

light not passing through a transparent object in eevee, is this just a limitation with eevee or am i missing something, I actually have a car model and i want the light to go through the windshield, but the windshield is just casting shadow. why????

Comment: Look on properties/material/settings/shadow mode.  Don't use "opaque".  Probably, use "none".

Comment: it worked, thanks